# Can't send array of dynamically created objects from qml to c++ as method parameter

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I am creating registered qml objects and storing them in javascript array. I want to send them as `QVariantList` method parameter to c++. Below is the code. However first cout of `Backend::sendItems` method doesn't print size. Weirdly it just prints "ze" and nothing else like thread is interrupted halfway. What am I doing wrong? You can also suggest another way of achieving what I want.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "backend.h"
#include "custom_class.h"

void register_Qml_types() {
  qmlRegisterType<Backend>("customApi", 1, 0, "Backend");
  qmlRegisterType<CustomClass>("customApi", 1, 0, "CustomClass");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

  register_Qml_types();
  QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
  engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

  return app.exec();
}
```

**custom_class.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_H
#define CUSTOM_H

#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class CustomClass : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)

public:
  CustomClass(QObject* parent = 0)
    : QObject(parent)
  {}

  CustomClass(QString name) {
    name_ = name;
  }

  CustomClass(const CustomClass& item) {
    name_ = item.name_;
  }

  QString name() const {
    return name_;
  }

  void setName(QString name) {
    name_ = name;
  }

private:
  QString name_;
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CustomClass)

#endif
```

**backend.h**

```
#ifndef BACKEND_H
#define BACKEND_H

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QVariant>
#include "custom_class.h"

class Backend : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Backend(QObject* parent = nullptr)
    : QObject(parent)
  {}

  Q_INVOKABLE void sendItems(const QVariantList& list) {
    std::cout << "size " + list.size() << std::endl;
    list_.clear();
    for(const QVariant& variant : list) {
      if(variant.canConvert<CustomClass>()) {
        CustomClass* custom = new CustomClass(variant.value<CustomClass>());
        list_.append(custom);
        std::cout << "converted" << std::endl;
      }
    }

  }

private:
    QList<CustomClass*> list_;
};

#endif
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick 2.11
import customApi 1.0

Window {
  id: root
  visible: true
  width: 500
  height: 500

  property var items: []

  Backend {
    id: backend
  }

  Row {
    Button {
      text: "button1"
      onClicked: {
        var item1 = Qt.createQmlObject("import customApi 1.0; CustomClass { name: \"first-name\" }", root);
        var item2 = Qt.createQmlObject("import customApi 1.0; CustomClass { name: \"second-name\" }", root);
        items.push(item1);
        items.push(item2);
      }
    }
    Button {
      text: "button2"
      onClicked: {
        backend.sendItems(items);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are printing:

```
std::cout << "size " + list.size() << std::endl;
```

but instead you must separate because probably it is considering size() as char.

```
std::cout << "size "<< list.size() << std::endl;
```

On the other hand `QObject`s are stored as a pointer, ie: `CustomClass *`, and also you are creating other `CustomClass *` not those that are in QML (I assume you want to have the same items in the view)

The solution is the next:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void sendItems(const QVariantList& list) {
    std::cout << "size "<< list.size() << std::endl;
    list_.clear();
    for(const QVariant& variant : list) {
        if(variant.canConvert<CustomClass *>()) {
            CustomClass* custom = variant.value<CustomClass*>();
            list_.append(custom);
            std::cout << "converted " << custom->name().toStdString() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the test project in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51747950)

Comment: Thanks your answer is correct but I don't want to get actual qml objects. Are these objects actually javascript objects in the view? If I change their properties( defined with Q_PROPERTY) in c++ do values of objects in javascript also change?

Comment: @AlpHancıoğlu Obvious, if they are the same of the QML (with my code does that) if you change the property in C ++ they will be reflected in QML. In your initial code you were creating other items. I recommend you not to think that QML is js. QML uses an engine similar to js but they are not necessarily the same.